# Material UI table rows drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-sortable-hoc

I'm trying to make my table rows draggable by using react-sortable-hoc. But I can't make it work correctly, can someone explain what am I'm doing wrong? My example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-cherry-dtkl5?file=/src/App.js